# Array Rotation function changing Original Array

Tags: python, arrays

The code is supposed to make a copy of the original array and rotate it (turn the columns into rows) while keeping the original array the same but the original array changes without a reason.

This is most likely a deep copy issue but I have tried using `copy.copy()` and it has not worked

Code:

```
l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

def rotate(funcl):
    funcl = funcl[::-1]
    
    for s1 in range(0, len(funcl)):
        for s2 in range(s1, len(funcl)):
            funcl[s1][s2], funcl[s2][s1] = funcl[s2][s1], funcl[s1][s2]

    return funcl

print("Original Array:\n", l)
nextl = rotate(l)
print("Original Array after Function:\n", l)
print("New Rotated Array:\n", nextl)
```

Output:

```
Original Array:
 [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
Original Array after Function:
 [[9, 6, 3], [8, 5, 2], [7, 4, 1]]
New Rotated Array:
 [[7, 4, 1], [8, 5, 2], [9, 6, 3]]
```

As you can see the function works fine but changes the original array

Comment: When you pass lists as parameters the original list gets changed (have a look at mutable and immutable objects). You'd need to make a copy of the original list (`l.copy()`).

Comment: What you're describing is matrix transposing, have you taken a look at the numpy library?

Comment: @Einliterflasche Sorry I am not understanding do you mean this: ```nextl = rotate(l.copy())```

Comment: @Yash No, in the function, or pass a copy as an argument (have a look at the answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`deepcopy` is notoriously slow and should be avoided if you can.

`zip()` is frequently used to transpose lists in python. Here the only wrinkle is that you want to reverse them. You can use `reversed()` for this and get a very succinct:

```
l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

def rotate(funcl):
      return list(zip(*reversed(funcl)))

print("Original Array:\n", l)
nextl = rotate(l)
print("Original Array after Function:\n", l)
print("New Rotated Array:\n", nextl)
```

Which prints:

```
Original Array:
 [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
Original Array after Function:
 [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
New Rotated Array:
 [(7, 4, 1), (8, 5, 2), (9, 6, 3)]
```

If it's important to maintain inner lists rather than tuples, you can add a map to mix:

```
l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

def rotate(funcl):
      return list(map(list, zip(*reversed(funcl))))
      # or return [list(t) for t in zip(*reversed(funcl))]

rotate(l)
# [[7, 4, 1], [8, 5, 2], [9, 6, 3]]
```

Comment: Is it possible to have lists inside instead of tuples ?

Comment: @Malo, yes, I added an edit for that.

Comment: @Mark I am confused on how the ```*``` works

Comment: @Yash it spreads the lists out as individual arguments to zip like calling `zip([7,8,9], [4,5,6], [1,2,3])` with three arguments.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to do a deepcopy with copy.deepcopy() before passing it to the function so every levels and nested sublevels of your list are duplicated:

```
import copy

l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

def rotate(funcl):
    funcl = funcl[::-1]
    
    for s1 in range(0, len(funcl)):
        for s2 in range(s1, len(funcl)):
            funcl[s1][s2], funcl[s2][s1] = funcl[s2][s1], funcl[s1][s2]

    return funcl

print("Original Array:\n", l)
nextl = rotate(copy.deepcopy(l))
print("Original Array after Function:\n", l)
print("New Rotated Array:\n", nextl)
```

output is:

```
Original Array:
 [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
Original Array after Function:
 [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
New Rotated Array:
 [[7, 4, 1], [8, 5, 2], [9, 6, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that works (plus a nicer way to print these lists):

```
def printlst(arr):
    for row in arr:
        print(*row)

def rotate(funcl):
    newl = [row.copy() for row in funcl]
    newl = newl[::-1]
    
    for s1 in range(0, len(newl)):
        for s2 in range(s1, len(newl)):
            newl[s1][s2], newl[s2][s1] = newl[s2][s1], newl[s1][s2]

    return newl


l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

print("Original Array:")
printlst(l)
nextl = rotate(l)
print("Original Array after Function:")
printlst(l)
print("New Rotated Array:")
printlst(nextl)
```

The resulting output:

```
Original Array:
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
Original Array after Function:
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
New Rotated Array:
7 4 1
8 5 2
9 6 3
```

An alternative approach:

```
def rotate(funcl):
    return [[funcl[j][i] for j in range(len(funcl))[::-1]] for i in range(len(funcl))]
```

Comment: For what it's worth this almost 5x slower than using `zip()`.

Comment: @Mark I was looking to make only a minimal change to the original function. I'm curious about how using `zip()` compares to Serge's approach; that's probably what I would have done

Comment: It also fails on a list like `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]`. See zip answer below.

Comment: It also only handles only 1 level of nested lists. Otherwise use copy.deepcopy if needed.

Comment: @Mark Oh, I meant the modification along the lines of my comment. So the method to compare would be `
def rotate(funcl):  \n    return [[funcl[j][i] for j in range(len(funcl))[::-1]] for i in range(len(funcl))]`

Comment: @Mark See the "alternative approach" in my edited answer. Anyway, I checked and it looks like the `zip()` method averages 3.6 x faster

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a deep copy issue: `funcl = funcl[::-1]` only does a shallow copy.

Anyway the Pythonic way would be to directly build the tranposed array with a double list comprehension avoiding a copy followed with a *rotation* :

```
def rotate(funcl):
   return [[funcl[j][i] for j in range(len(funcl))] for i in range(len(funcl))]
```

Comment: You've reflected the array instead of rotating. You should instead have something like `return [[funcl[j][i] for j in range(len(funcl))[::-1]] for i in range(len(funcl))]`.